# Question about sample size for each class for machine learning classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, unbalanced-classes, fraud-detection

I'm trying to use a machine learning classifier (SVM in particular) on data that I generate. Unlike other applications, the data is not given to me but rather I have the flexibility to generate how much I need, albeit with costs.

My data only has 2 classes (class A and class B). If I were to respect the probability distribution of the data, I'd end up with an imbalanced class. Class A occurs with a significantly smaller probability than the other, something like fraud detection.

To address this, I am planning to generate more samples for Class A, i.e. oversampling it. I must also say that generating samples for Class A is much more costly than generating samples for Class B (I have an approximation that I trust for Class B).

If I were to oversample Class A, setting costs of sampling aside, would the ideal situation be for both classes to have the same number of samples? Or, can I still oversample Class A but with fewer samples than Class B and use weighted SVM to address the imbalance?

Also, for the test data, should the proportion of samples in each class be equivalent to the proportions in the training data?

I would appreciate thoughts on the issue, if you have any experience with this situation.

Comment: Hi, you might want to read about active learning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning), where you kind of interactively decide which data points are worth getting labels on. In this way, you may be a bit more economical with your input data, and can e.g. decide to get labels on the next set of data points because you think those points would give you the greatest information gain or improve your classifier the most, etc.

Comment: I suspect that an important issue may be an asymmetric cost of misclassification errors: labelling Class A items as B may be more or less costly than labelling Class B items as A.  For your test set, I suspect you need enough of each class to be able to judge the quality of your final model, which if misclassification is uncommon for a particular class may require more of that item.  But if your test set can be big enough anyway, than making it match the real world application may bring other benefits

Comment: @Henry, I will be using those precision and recall curves to test my classifier. But I'm really curious if you can optimally design the number of data points OR if this is one of those: it depends on the data set at hand